# global function import with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

lets say I have a huge js file with global functions like:

```
function a() ....
function b() ....
```

How can I import them to a webpack bundle and use? require/import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to add your function to `webpack` is:

1) create new `js` file in assets  for example `assets/js/fnc.js` is our file name.

2) Import `fnc.js` to app for example I use the vue.

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
    ...
    import Fnc from '@/assets/js/fnc.js';
    import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
    ...
```

Then you can use your functions : )

> Note: define functions by this pattern:
>
> ```
> a = function () {
>   alert(1);
>   return  false;
> }
>
> b = function () {
>   alert(2);
>   return  false;
> }
> ```
>
> Don't define with your pattern and don't use `var` or `let` before
>   function name.